# Upload file with ionic and Wakanda

Tags: upload, ionic-framework, wakanda

I try to upload file directly to an Image field.

When i try my dev on the browser, everything works fine (http://127.0.0.1:8100/ionic-lab).
The file upload correctly.

When i try on my android phone, I got a 403 Fordidden error

I enable the file upload Service in the settings file.
I add in the file persmissions.xml the following :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<permissions>
    <allow type="service" action="upload" resource="upload" groupName="Admin" groupID="01000000000000000000000000000000" temporaryForcePermissions="false"/>
</permissions>`
```

My code is the following :

```
var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
$scope.book.Image.$upload(file).$promise.then(function (e) {
    $scope.book.$save();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It could come from a CORS problem.
So try to add these lines in the config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*"/> 
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

If it is not working, try to restore the state of your mobile application.
to do that, go into the mobile folder of your project and execute this line `ionic state restore`.

If this command line fail. Erase the platforms folder in your mobile folder and execute `ionic state restore` another time.

I hope that will help you.